# Connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse from Mac OS X

Tags: macos, azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse from the command line on my MacBook with [sql-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli). With the following connection string, the login just hangs ("Connecting to .database.windows.net....")

```
$ mssql -s <serverName>.database.windows.net -u <userName>@<serverName> -p <password> -d <dwName>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL DW requires an encrypted connection. Using the "-e" in the connection string solves the problem:

```
$ mssql -s <serverName>.database.windows.net -u <userName>@<serverName> -p <password> -d <dwName> -e
```